# Autocomplete people picker in sharepoint2010

Tags: people-picker, javascript

I have a problem in which I have to add an Auto Complete functionality for a new people picker of Sharepoint list newform.aspx

While Googling I found this

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/autocomplete-for-sharepoint-people-picker.aspx

Which is helpful but there are 2 main problems :

1.

```
  it will pick data from a custom list
  I want it to pick data from user profiles (directly from Sharepoint user profiles)
```

2.

```
  it doesn't work with out of the box people picker
  it works with a custom textbox though
```

Please help me out resolving these.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use the Javascript Client Object Model for this. Failing that you may need to use [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558879%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is the very good article which is for MOSS 2007. But I am sure it will work for SP2010 and SP2013.

It shows how to create custom people picker inheriting OOTB people picker control. Hope it will help you.

http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/peopleeditor-control/

You can use this PeopleEditor control when developing application pages or control templates using the following syntax:

```
<spuc:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditor1" runat="server" width="350px"
               AllowEmpty="true" MultiSelect="false" SelectionSet="User"  />
```

But only after you have added a directive at the top of the application page or control template:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="spuc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
         Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

If you are developing a web part you have to create the PeopleEditor control completely in code:

```
private PeopleEditor peopleEditor;
private void EnsureChildControls()
{
peopleEditor = new PeopleEditor();
peopleEditor.AutoPostBack = true;
peopleEditor.ID = "PeopleEditor1";
peopleEditor.AllowEmpty = false;
peopleEditor.MultiSelect = false;
Panel1.Controls.Add(peopleEditor);
}
```

This control is part of the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and is located in the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namespace.