# How to allow for autocomplete Person/Group for a new custom site column of type Person or group

Tags: development, active-directory, publishing-page, site-column

I have added a new site column named “Assinged To” of type “Person or Group”, then I added it to the page layout.

The final result was that I can search for our active directory user/groups.but if I start typing a string inside the column then no autocomplete will occur. For example I type “joh” but it did not autocomplete the results (john).

[image]

So is there a way to add this feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is no OOTB feature in SharePoint 2010 but you can achieve it using Jquery.

Please refer the below links it would help you.
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/autocomplete-for-sharepoint-people-picker.aspx

[Autocomplete people picker in sharepoint2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/autocomplete-people-picker-in-sharepoint2010)

http://spjsblog.com/2010/03/25/autocomplete-for-sharepoint-people-picker/

For SharePoint 2013 it works, just wait after typing the name for some seconds. Sometimes it takes time to load the username.

---

According to your post, my understanding is that autocomplete for people picker field is not working in custom layout form.

People picker loses its autocomplete functionality and defaults to the old style on a form page other than the default form.

As a workflow around, you can add the JavaScript Code to the form page in the SharePoint Designer to add autocomplete functionality.

For more information, you can refer to: [Javascript Reference Link](http://oddmithril.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/sharepoint-2013-peoplepicker/)

---

There is a new control called ClientPeoplePicker.

You can change the "`<SharePoint:FormField" to "<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker`" to display as the new control.

However, you need to add function to get and set the value to the control.

More information:[ClientPeoplePicker in SharePoint 2013](http://spobject.blogspot.com/2013/02/clientpeoplepicker-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

Thanks!

Comment: All your links are for 2010, the screenshot above is for 2013 where SharePoint in some places uses a people picker with autocomplete. I guess OP wants to know how to use this new control himself

Comment: @RobertLindgren you are right i am using SP 2013. Hardik i have wait for sometimes but the people will not be autocompleted...

Comment: can you check it with the default list form if the auto complete works?

Comment: yes i have a tracking list and the default assinged to column is working well.

Comment: please check with the edited solution answer.it can help you then since people picker on default forms is working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when my SharePoint 2010 portal was migrated to SharePoint 2013. I created a new page layout and everything started working. But for old layout Autofill was not working at all. Verify using developer tools that below files are getting loaded:

1. clienttemplates.js
2. clientforms.js
3. clientpeoplepicker.js
4. autofill.js
5. SP.JS

If these files are not getting loaded then explicitly add reference to these files. And try with below javascript

```
                     <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
                <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
                <script src="/_layouts/15/clientform.js"></script>
                <script src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
                <script src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {
                        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
                        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
                        var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");
                        _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
                        var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
                        _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
                    }
                    SetUserFieldValue("Assigned To", "Domain\\UserID");
                </script>
```

Comment: i came across this problem again is that i want to have autocomplete with my current people picker field. now you mentioned that i can write the above script ,,but my question is where i need to write the script ? inside my master page ? or inside the edit and new aspx forms ?

Comment: @waqas can you adivce on how i can get the autocomplete to work with the people picker ?

Comment: You need to add this script on new and edit list forms.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding a complete drop-in solution for custom forms in SharePoint Designer, so with the help of some other resources I developed my own. I answered this another Stack Exchange post, which can be found here: [Permalink: Clientpeoplepicker control in custom SharePoint List form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/230589/24376)

To summarize, you add an old style picker as <SharePoint:FormField ... tag and a new style picker as <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ... tag for each form field that needs a picker and use javascript to copy values between them, hiding the old style SP2010 pickers on the page.  It requires careful setting of attributes.